# It is possible to have numberOfSectionsInTableView dynamically?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, tableview

Can I have the number of rows dynamically?
I'm trying to remove a tableView section header and I don'k know how... and I've taught that a solution would be to change the number of sections.

Right now my numberOfSectionsInTableView looks like:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 2;
}
```

and

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    beTribesAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [appDelegate.firstArray count];
        case 1:
            return [appDelegate.secondArray count];    
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

setting the title section like this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
    sectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [sectionTitles addObject:@"firstSection"];
        [sectionTitles addObject:@"secondSection"];
    NSString *sectionText = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionText;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the question as the answer seems trivial: just change the implementation to return some dynamic value and you are done, right?

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.nbSections;
}
```

Where `nbSections` is a property to which you will assign the value you want so you can change it at any time you want. So what's the matter then?

*PS: Of course, call `[tableView reloadData]` to recompute the content of your tableView and make the new value being taken into account obviously... maybe that's what you were missing?*

Comment: one more to go... I don't know where to place `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: Just after you change the value of nbSections. Read the "Table View Programming Guide" in Apple documentation it explains it all with sample code and generic principles about tableviews, sections, cells, etc

Comment: then I should place it inside `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method?

Comment: No. Calling `realoadData` **is** the stuff that will trigger the call to this method. place it when you plan to write `nbSections = ...` in your code. Really, go read the doc.

Comment: well I though setting in place, something like this:`AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.firstArray.count == 0) {
        numberOfSections = 1;
    } else {
        numberOfSections = 2;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

To remove the section header you must set the header height to 0 like so

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        default:
            return 44;
    }
}
```

this example will remove the first section header and all the others will be set to 44.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to move the sectionTitles array into a property on your view controller, and initialise it in your init method.

Then when you want to change the title of a section change the value in the array and call [tableView reloadData]

Do you want to remove the whole section from the tableView or just the header?  if you want to just remove the header set the item in the array to @""

If you want to remove the section altogether remove the item from sectionTitles and change your numberOfSectionsInTableView method to read:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return [sectionTitles count];
}
```